# facebook AppInviteContent: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first

Tags: android, facebook, delphi, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

When i try to Launch AppInviteContent like below :

```
 AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl("....")
            .setPreviewImageUrl("https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg")
            .build();
AppInviteDialog.show(activity, content);
```

i receive the error The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first:

```
04-09 02:46:50.429: W/System.err(5960): The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
04-09 02:46:50.429: W/System.err(5960):     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
04-09 02:46:50.429: W/System.err(5960):     at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:896)
04-09 02:46:50.429: W/System.err(5960):     at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:110)
04-09 02:46:50.429: W/System.err(5960):     at com.facebook.share.widget.AppInviteDialog.<clinit>(AppInviteDialog.java:75)
```

but i don't understand because FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize (Context) is deprecated now :( why i receive this error ?

i m under Delphi if it's matter

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? What happens if you call sdkInitialize?

Comment: I'm getting this too with Facebook SDK 4.24.0

Answer (score 3):

Just use the deprecated FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(); for now.

Auto-init uses content providers which fail on some devices with modified Android. I got thousands of crashes and uninstalls from my users.

I reported this issue months ago and they still didn't fix it, instead they just closed the issue.